# How does one update a stored procedure or a table to mimic a clone in another database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have three main servers we use for a project: development, preproduction and production.

We need the "preproduction" server to be as much as possible in sync with the production server, so we plan to, every two weeks, update everything in the database to match any new changes made in production in that period of time.

For the database information, we're using Linked servers, to retrieve the latest data from production. The problem is, how to do something similar for the stored procedures?

Is there a way to make it so that, if a change was made to a production server stored procedure, such change would be made also to preproduction without doing it manually? It can be somewhat slow, since we would do it throughout the night.

Same thing with any changes made to a table structure in that time, is there any way to detect it and run it? We would like a script we could run every two weeks, but if not possible, we could look into other options.

Comment: Usually this is done with a continuous integration (CI) solution.  Do you have your schema in source control?  Another option is to restore your preproduction environment from production backups.

Comment: No, the schema is not on source control. We just acquired dbForge, which can translate differences between databases to sql queries, and I think we could use that, I just wanted to see if there was a way to "programatically" do this, so we could just run a script or procedure, or even put it in an automatic rutine.

Comment: Source control/version control is the solution here

Answer (score 0):

[SqlPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver15) is the native SQL Server tool to generate schema drift scripts, and to deploy database schema changes.

Note you should deploy your changes to non-prod environments *first*, not last.

Comment: We deploy on development first, but want the current data on production to debug in preproduction first before deployment. Also, sometimes there are urgent bugs which we fix first on production for the business to keep running throughout the day, and then we deploy a more stable fix when it's ready.